# Heroku не видит procfile python

Tags: heroku, telegram, бот

В общем, создал я небольшого телеграм бота, решил запилить на сервере. Методом проб и ошибок дошел я до этапа развертки. Git просто не видит procfile. 
содержимое procfile:

web: python bot.py
[image: То, что показывает git]

[![Список файлов][2]][2]

[image: третий файл]

Comment: Ничего не выводится. просто пустая строка

Comment: On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: https://github.com/piller1997/bot

Comment: В общем, решил подключить через github на heroku. Опять та же ошибка 
 !     Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.
 !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
 ~     Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring.
 ~     Rename it to Procfile to have it honored.
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 56.9M
-----> Launching...

Comment: Я его уже сто раз переименовывал то с маленькой, то с большой

Comment: К тому же на пк он с большой.

Comment: Уррааа! Спасибо большое! Получилось!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас **Procfile** называется с маленькой буквы в репозитории. Поэтому при развертывании **Heroku** его не видит.

**Windows** не различает большие и маленькие буквы, а **git** различает. Поэтому несмотря на то, что вы его переименовали на локальном диске он по прежнему с маленькой.

Comment: А Linux различает?

Comment: @piller97 обычно да. Хотя можно найти драйверы файловых систем, которые не различают, это редкость.